# SQL statement where clause by age group

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I was having some problem when trying to get the age based on each age group using SQL statement.

**My account table**
[image]

I stored the age as birthDate in this table. Then I am running this SQL statement to get the age:

```
SELECT count(be.eventID) ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, str_to_date(a.birthDate,'%d/%m/%Y'), CURDATE()) AS age, a.gender, be.eventID
FROM account a INNER JOIN bookedevent be ON be.bookedEventBy = a.accountName
WHERE a.gender = 'M'
GROUP BY be.eventID
ORDER BY count(be.eventID) DESC
```

But with this SQL, I not sure how should I where clause by age group. Let's say there is age group 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50 and 50 and above. With this SQL, I am getting this result:

[image]

As you can see from here, there is a 2 which falls under another age group with those in 11-20. I wonder is it possible to differentiate the age group using SQL statement?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? Make your mind up! :)

Comment: Sorry sorry, I was testing this statement on MySQL workbench. Let me edit the tag

Comment: You want a another column to differentiate the age group or you want to filter the result based on age group

Comment: Please post a sample table of what you would want the output to be. Do you want them counted by age group? If so, how are `gender, eventID` relevant to the aggregate results?

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yeah I wanted them to be filtered by age group and gender for each event

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Because I wanted to know for each event there is how many male or female between this age group and sorted the count by descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Between` Operator to filter the result between two values.

```
SELECT Count(be.eventID),
       Timestampdiff(YEAR, Str_to_date(a.birthDate, '%d/%m/%Y'), Curdate()) AS age,
       a.gender,
       be.eventID
FROM   account a
       INNER JOIN bookedevent be
               ON be.bookedEventBy = a.accountName
WHERE  a.gender = 'M'
       AND Timestampdiff(YEAR, Str_to_date(a.birthDate, '%d/%m/%Y'), Curdate()) 
           BETWEEN 11 AND 20 -- Here you can define the range to be filtered
GROUP  BY be.eventID
ORDER  BY Count(be.eventID) DESC
```